# instagram scope not working with passport

Tags: node.js, passport.js, instagram-api

```
{
  error_type: "OAuthException",
  code: 400,
  error_message: "Invalid scope field(s): public_content"
}
```

Above it the error i am getting and this is all sudden, i was able to login and signup using same code but suddenly i am facing this error.

I made sure nothing changed in instagram application setting and permission is also approved for `public_content`.

Is there anything deprecated or anything wrong from today because this was working before 8 hours of so.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem and got round it by removing 'public_access' from the requested scope permissions.

So our requested scope now is just 'basic' in our code and it works ok.

Comment: Yeah i did the same and it worked and noticed there is change in instagram APi as they will also remove basic support by 2020 and asked to use Graph APi.